# Is this a proof of a mathematical statement using physics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, voltage, mathematics

In problem 3.16 of "Introduction to Electrodynamics" by D. J. Griffiths, we are told to find the potential inside a cube, 5 sides of which are at zero potential, and the remaining side (insulated from the others) is at potential $V_0$.

Solving Laplace's equation, we get that the potential is given by

$$ V(x, y, z) = \frac{16V_0}{\pi^2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{(2i+1)\pi x}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{(2j+1)\pi y}{a}\right)\sinh\left(\frac{\sqrt{(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2}\pi z}{a}\right)}{(2i+1)(2j+1)\sinh\left(\sqrt{(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2}\pi\right)} .$$

We are then asked to calculate the value of this potential at the center of the cube. Subbing in the point $\left(\frac{a}{2}, \frac{a}{2}, \frac{a}{2}\right)$, we get

$$ V_{center} = \frac{8V_0}{\pi^2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(2i+1)(2j+1)\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2}\pi}{2}\right)}.$$

Interestingly, we can also use the principle of superposition to solve the question by considering a cube with all 6 sides being at potential $V_0$. In this case, solving Laplace's equation simply yields $V = V_0 $ everywhere, including the center. By symmetry, we know that each side contributes equally to the potential at the center, and hence we get that $V_{center} = \frac{V_0}{6}$ in the initial problem. Together, this yields
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(2i+1)(2j+1)\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2}\pi}{2}\right)} = \frac{\pi^2}{48},$$
which numerically seems to be true.

Question:

Is solving this problem in these 2 different ways technically a proof of the final equation? If so, I find it simply amazing that a mathematical statement is being proven using a mathematical model in the context of physics.

Also, is there any other way to mathematically prove that the double summation equals to $\frac{\pi^2}{48}$?

Edit: I have discovered a mathematical proof of this result and have detailed it in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4783797/1231048).

Comment: Where's the physics? This is *all* mathematics.

Comment: Your argument seems right to me (though it's been long enough since I've done electromagnetism that I don't want to say definitively there's not some subtle problem). But, more generally, a comment on your first question, is that this is often how a connection between math and physics is made. Physical intuition gives you two ways of looking at one problem, that might not be obvious purely mathematically, and the two ways naturally give you two different answers that have to be equal by consistency.

Comment: You may want to check out Levi, Mark. The mathematical mechanic: using physical reasoning to solve problems. Princeton University Press, 2009.

Comment: I confirmed the numerical calculation: I get $\pi^2/48$ at double precision.

Comment: *I find it simply amazing that a mathematical statement is being proven using a mathematical model in the context of physics.* You may find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine) interesting as an unexpected and significant mathematical discovery proved using ideas from physics.